# How to use Renderscript in lockscreen

Tags: android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, live-wallpaper, lockscreen

I was doing a research on livewallpaper these days, it's easy to use RenderscriptGL, but when I want to use it in the lockscreen, then the problem started. Although I modified the frameworks\base\policy\Android.mk. Add $(call all-renderscript-files-under, src), but it still couldn't generate the ScriptC file.

I don't know where the problem is. Does anyone come acrossed the same problem and give me some help?

Answer (score 2):

Add line like below

```
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += core/java/com/android/internal/widget/waterwave/fall.rs
```

on your `$(ANDROID)/frameworks/base/Android.mk`

maybe this could resolve your issue.